# QT make has large output on build

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, makefile

I am compiling a QT project. I ran qmake and the make to compile.

Every time it compiles a cpp there is like 20 lines of verbose output.

When I just do a change one line and make, it will be 20 lines of output for that one change.

What exactly is this output, and is there a way to limit it?

This following output is from changing a single line and compiling that single cpp.

```
g++ -c -g -Wextra -std=c++0x -DGLOGG_DATE=\"`date +"%F"`\" -DGLOGG_VERSION=\"`git describe`\" -DGLOGG_COMMIT=\"`git rev-parse --short HEAD`\" -DGLOGG_SUPPORTS_INOTIFY -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DFILELOG_MAX_LEVEL="logDEBUG" -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Isrc -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I.moc/release-shared -I.ui/release-shared -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o .obj/release-shared/filterset.o src/filterset.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o release/glogg .obj/release-shared/main.o .obj/release-shared/session.o .obj/release-shared/abstractlogdata.o .obj/release-shared/logdata.o .obj/release-shared/logfiltereddata.o .obj/release-shared/logfiltereddataworkerthread.o .obj/release-shared/logdataworkerthread.o .obj/release-shared/compressedlinestorage.o .obj/release-shared/mainwindow.o .obj/release-shared/crawlerwidget.o .obj/release-shared/abstractlogview.o .obj/release-shared/logmainview.o .obj/release-shared/filteredview.o .obj/release-shared/optionsdialog.o .obj/release-shared/persistentinfo.o .obj/release-shared/configuration.o .obj/release-shared/filtersdialog.o .obj/release-shared/filterset.o .obj/release-shared/savedsearches.o .obj/release-shared/infoline.o .obj/release-shared/menuactiontooltipbehavior.o .obj/release-shared/selection.o .obj/release-shared/quickfind.o .obj/release-shared/quickfindpattern.o .obj/release-shared/quickfindwidget.o .obj/release-shared/sessioninfo.o .obj/release-shared/recentfiles.o .obj/release-shared/overview.o .obj/release-shared/overviewwidget.o .obj/release-shared/marks.o .obj/release-shared/quickfindmux.o .obj/release-shared/signalmux.o .obj/release-shared/tabbedcrawlerwidget.o .obj/release-shared/viewtools.o .obj/release-shared/encodingspeculator.o .obj/release-shared/gloggapp.o .obj/release-shared/platformfilewatcher.o .obj/release-shared/inotifywatchtowerdriver.o .obj/release-shared/watchtower.o .obj/release-shared/watchtowerlist.o .obj/release-shared/qrc_glogg.o .obj/release-shared/moc_abstractlogdata.o .obj/release-shared/moc_logdata.o .obj/release-shared/moc_logfiltereddata.o .obj/release-shared/moc_logfiltereddataworkerthread.o .obj/release-shared/moc_logdataworkerthread.o .obj/release-shared/moc_mainwindow.o .obj/release-shared/moc_crawlerwidget.o .obj/release-shared/moc_abstractlogview.o .obj/release-shared/moc_optionsdialog.o .obj/release-shared/moc_filtersdialog.o .obj/release-shared/moc_filewatcher.o .obj/release-shared/moc_quickfind.o .obj/release-shared/moc_quickfindpattern.o .obj/release-shared/moc_quickfindwidget.o .obj/release-shared/moc_menuactiontooltipbehavior.o .obj/release-shared/moc_overviewwidget.o .obj/release-shared/moc_quickfindmux.o .obj/release-shared/moc_tabbedcrawlerwidget.o .obj/release-shared/moc_externalcom.o .obj/release-shared/moc_viewtools.o .obj/release-shared/moc_gloggapp.o .obj/release-shared/moc_platformfilewatcher.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lboost_program_options -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you have when running `make` is the commands that are executed to compile your project.

If you want to remove these outputs you can use `CONFIG+=silent` either in your .pro file or when calling `qmake`:

```
qmake CONFIG+=silent myproject.pro
make
```

Doing so will generate shorter outputs e.g

```
compiling file1.cpp 
compiling file2.cpp
linking app.exe
```

---

In details, when you change a cpp file you should see 2 lines in your output. One for the command that compile your cpp file into an object file and one for the command that will link the new object file (and the ones that did not change) into a new executable. That is exactly the output you pasted. If you remove all the options, you end up with:

```
g++ -c -o .obj/release-shared/filterset.o src/filterset.cpp
g++ -o release/glogg <list of object files>
```

You can see it as more lines because the console you are using wraps lines that are too long on many lines.

Also not that if you edit a .h file it is normal to have way more file to recompile as all cpp files that directly or indirectly include the changed .h file will have to be recompiled. And since you are using Qt, if you change a .h file of a QObject derived class, you will have 2 extra commands executed: one for generating the moc.cpp file and another for compiling the moc.cpp file.